# How can I display image from Laravel Storage to vue front-end

Tags: laravel, image, vue.js

I am saving an image in Laravel Storage persiting the path ant the database like this:

```
if($request->hasFile('avatar')) 
      {
        $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
        $path = $avatar->store('images/profile');

         $thumbnailName = "avatar".Date('YMdhis');
        $avatar->move(public_path('images/profile'), $thumbnailName);

      }
      //Save path to the database
      $avatar_path = new UserProfile;
      $avatar_path->avatar = $path;
      $avatar_path->save();

  The challenge  I am having is displaying the image in VueJs front. Here is my vue template:



<img :src="profile.avatar" alt="Profile Photo Image" width="200" height="200" class="img-thumbnail"/>

//This obviously does not work because profile.avatar contains relative 
path of the image as saved in the database
  **JavaScript**
<script>
      export default
{
    name:'ListProfile',
    data(){
        return{

          profile:{} //storing image path as fetched from database

        }
    },
    }
      </script>
```

I have also symlinked from 'public/storage' to 'storage/app  using artisan command storage:link

This is my base url in main.js :

```
 axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/'
```

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should return the url with the help of Storage facade, try to get the url like this:

`Storage::url($profile->avatar)`

Are you just returning the model from the controller?

Comment: I am returning a model from a controller and image is among other data I am returning. Then I am looping with v-for directive: <div v-for="profile in profiles"><img :src="profile.avatar"></div>

Comment: using the Storage facade as indicated pre-appends /storage on image path beign retrieved from database. adding the baseurl results to something like: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/storage/my/image/path/image.jpg something that again is not working.

Comment: Storage::url should return absolute path like this: /storage/images/profile/xxx.jpg, and the file should be accessible. Check to see if file is really saved to storage/app/public/images/profile maybe the problem is with upload and check if you can manually access the image by typing the url in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

just use url() helper in backend to generate a full url to the picture and pass it as a prop to the vue component.

```
$profile->avatar = url($profile->avatar);
```

and then pass $profile (or just directly create and pass $avatar, depending on your needs) to Vue as a prop.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img :src="/uploads/ + profile.avatar">
```

my folder structure is public/uploads/